# Dependancies for a .py file

Tags: python, python-2.7, dependencies

Given a .py file in our local system, is there a way to find its dependancies?
By dependancies I mean the import statements that we specify.

tried pip show [package name] but it does not give the dependancies for a .py file in our local system

Comment: Well yes: open the file and checks the import statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `freeze` to get all the dependencies installed in your environment. (This will list all the dependencies even though you have not used it in the project but installed.)

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

If you want to list only the used ones use `pipreqs`,

```
pip install pipreqs
```

then,

```
pipreqs path/to/project
```